# Rate of convergence of numerical methods like Secant method ,Regula Falsi method,Newton Raphson method.

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, online-resources

Is there any good resource which has a good introduction to rate of convergence of numerical methods . I searched but unable to find one.

Any kind of material,video lectures,books,links is great.

Comment: [Traub's book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=se3YdgFgz4YC) is a pretty standard reference.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the speed of convergence is given whenever the method is introduced with an in-depth discussion of convergence.

**Secant method:** golden ratio as order of convergence in the case that the iteration converges at all.

**Regula Falsi:** Convergence is assured by bracketing, convergence speed is linear in most cases due to stalling of one of the bracketing interval ends. With anti-stalling variations the number of steps is roughly double that of the secant method for the same level of error reduction.

**Newton:** Order 2 convergence close to a simple root. However, the evaluation of the derivative has the cost of 1 to 2 function evaluations, so in that measure, function evaluations rather than iteration steps, it may be slower than the secant method. See Ostrowski index.

Comment: This helped me but i was searching for the resources like video lectures !